# How to create ASCII time-series ﬁles to make TSM_GUI in TIMESAT?

Tags: convert, remote-sensing, time, ascii

I would like to create TSM_GUI in TIMESAT, but as an input I have to choose ASCII time-series ﬁles, but I have only .tif images.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As per section 9.9 of the [TIMESAT manual](http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/docs/TIMESAT32_software_manual.pdf):

> Convert all images into flat (header less) binary format.[...] File conversion can
>   be carried out with software such as the open source Geospatial Abstraction Data Base
>   Library (GDAL)

On [GDAL Raster Format](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) that suffices would be [ENVI .hdr labelled Raster](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#ENVI)

You can use `gdal_translate` to convert your GeoTiffs into this format:

```
gdal_translate -of ENVI input.tif output.bil
```

This will convert the GeoTiff to a binary file and a separate header file (.hdr labelled).

Depending on your input data you might also have to convert the datatype with the `-ot` option.

> The file type should be one of
>   the following: 8-bit unsigned integer, 16-bit signed integer, 32-bit real. For 16-bit signed
>   integer please also determine if it is little or big endian byte order. The checks on the
>   images are best done using TSM_imageview